# Issue with planet planet getting Atom feed from Wordpress Sites

Tags: wordpress, atom-feed

I am using [Planet Planet](http://planetplanet.org/) for feed aggregation and showing it as a Planet, similar to [GNOME Planet](http://planet.gnome.org/). However recently for last few days I see that some of the blogs have started throwing Error 500 in the output of the Planet run when it runs to get the feed from a wordpress site. This is a [sample feed](http://fsmkblog.wordpress.com/feed/atom/) or [this](http://farhaanbukhsh.wordpress.com/feed/atom/?tag=fsmk) in my planet. I am not sure if it some issue with the planet code or something that was recently changed in Wordpress site. 
Anyone else facing similar issue or anything new with respect to Atom feed from wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Both those URLs are returning:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

in both cases pointed to `https` versions. Other than that, they're serving well-formed, valid Atom feeds.

You'll need to investigate whether Planet Planet is failing to cope with that or if you have some other misconfiguration.

Comment: This was the same earlier also. Planet handles this part well and it was working ok. Not sure what got modified recently.